# Passing values from button click event to jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I have following code behind button click event:

```
 protected void buttonAccept_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      string dataTable;
      DataTable tbl1 = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;     
 }
```

I need to have both dataTable and tbl1 used from #buttonAccept

```
 $("#buttonAccept").ajaxSubmit(
                  "./test/writeToDb"
                  , function (response) {
                      Info(
                         "DataSaved."     
                         }
                      );
```

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

var gvTable = $('#GridView1').dataTable();

I think that will give you the datatable to access.

As for the dataTable string. Could you use a hiddenfield, populate it in the Click method, then reference it in the ajaxSubmit client side event?